# javascript json parse from URL

Tags: javascript, json

UPDATED:

I'm trying to parse a response from a URL but have no idea if I'm doing it correctly.

**The URL returns the following JSON:**

```
{"make":"truck","date":"23 July 2009","colour":"pink"};
```

If i replace var newtext = xhttp.responseText; with

var newtext = '{"make":"truck","date":"23 July 2009","colour":"pink"}';

it works but as soon as i go back to the xhttp.responseText it just shows a blank page.

**The code I'm using is:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://url.com", false);
  xhttp.send();

  var newtext = xhttp.responseText;

  var obj = JSON.parse(newtext);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    obj.make + "<br>" +
    obj.colour + "<br>" +
    obj.date;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: your response is already a JSON , why you are again parsing it? just use it without parsing.

Comment: @SindhooOad because the JSON is being retrieved from `xhttp.responseText`, I'm pretty sure it's a string that happens to be in the JSON format and does need to be parsed

Comment: @NewToCode then remove that comma, and you have closing single quote but not starting, is this type mistake here or in code as well?

Comment: i just get a blank page, if i view source i can see the script and the target paragraph but there's nothing else there.

Comment: I am sure you would be getting error on browser console, and it is because of comma.

Comment: @NewToCode does the target paragraph have the `<br>` tags in it when you view the source?

Comment: @jonhopkins no its just completely empty.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @jonhopkins, oops i didn't check, just checked and it says test.html:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: xhttp is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined your variable `xhttp`, but you are trying to call functions on it. This is resulting in the `Uncaught ReferenceError` error and causing the rest of the code not to run. To create an `XMLHttpRequest` object as you appear to be trying to do, put this at the top of your script.

```
var xhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// the object actually exists here now so the functions can be called on it
xhttp.open("GET", "https://url.com", false);
xhttp.send();
...
```

Then you can continue on with the rest of your code, assured that your `xhttp` object has been initialized.

I don't normally recommend using w3schools, but the above code was copied from http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp